# Implementing Feedback Alignment in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, gradient-descent

I want to implement Direct Feedback Alignemnt in Tensorflow.

Reference paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.01596v5.pdf, Nøkland (2016)

I implemented a simple network that does DFA in pure Python, having explicitly the backprop, I just switched the backward pass of BP with the one of DFA.

[image: Backward passes]

where B1 and B2 are two random matrices with appropriate dimensions.

Tensorflow training obviously does backprop by default. Where and what should I modify in Tensorflow code in order to get this training behavior?

Comment: https://github.com/sangyi92/feedback_alignment

Comment: You could take example from the https://github.com/xuexue/randombp tensorflow implementation where optimisation step is manually defined using Direct Feedback Alignment, instead of using the automatic GradientDescentOptimizer method.